# My PHP code is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I need a little help. I am trying to get my PHP code (saved as a separate file named lulzy.php) to work but it just doesn't want to. What is it that I am doing wrong???

My goal is to get the users message directly into my e-mail inbox and right upon the user fills out my web form.

Here is the link to my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8S82T/127/

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  $name= $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  mail( "mymail@gmail.com", "Feedback Form Results",
    $message, "From: $email" );
  header( 'Location: Index.html' );
?>
```

Everything is in the same folder on my desktop.

This is the message I receive when I try to fill the whole form and send a message:

Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Users/MS/Desktop/Slide Down Contact Me Form/lulzy.php

Comment: +1 for the 127 tries plus the cool script.

Comment: Your form is vulnerable to mail header injection. Always whitelist `$email` before putting it into the headers.

Comment: Try changing this bit: `action="lulzy.php"` to `action="./lulzy.php"` or different variants.

Comment: @Marcel Please feel free to edit this form at JSFiddle and repost the link here. I am very new to web design so I am trying to figure out how lot of things work while I am reading a lot of suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @C.Felipe The jsfiddle is pretty much useless because there is no "lulzy.php" file on their site so it can never work there. You're not getting the same error there, are you?

Comment: It's not the JSFiddle that's wrong, you need to change your PHP code: check that `$email` contains a valid email address with [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var), otherwise a spammer will be able to inject a Bcc field.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel , why do you say so? Firefox cannot even find the php file, so...

Comment: My web form works fine on JSFiddle (without php) but when I copy/paste everything in separate folder and when I add lulzy.php file it doesn't want to send the message to my e-mail. Don't know why?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos: I didn't post that as an answer to the question, but a general suggestion to the posted code. OP: As pXL already said, you need to run your script from a server (that can send mail).

Comment: When you copy it to the same folder, does it still give you the same error? Try writing the full path in action, starting by: `file:///`

Comment: @Marcel It seems like you understand my problem. I need to edit PHP in order to receive the users message directly into my inbox. The PHP code above is not working for me. I guess the problem is in the HEADER line at the bottom which says header( 'Location: Index.html' );

Comment: No, it's because, as already stated, you run your script from your local hard drive, instead of from a server.

Comment: So, the code is correct but it doesn't work because everything is on my hard drive? And it will work once when I put it on server? AmI correct? But how can I test this before I upload everything to a server??? Thank guys!

Comment: Run a server on the box where you're writing the scripts: xampp, mamp whatever your platform

Comment: @Mark Baker Sorry, but I am very new to web development. Could you please be more specific? Any links to a place where I can test/run my work so far??? Thanks for understanding and patience!

Comment: I mean that many developers run apache/php/MySQL on the box where they actually write their scripts so that they can test them before uploading them to the server.... depending on whether your local PC is a Windows, Linux or Mac box, then you can find apache/php/MySQL packages available for you PC.... just google "mamp" or "xampp" to find these packages

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thanks. I believe this solves my question. Thank you all good people!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think none of the answers here contain the actual solution for this error message:

> Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Users/MS/Desktop/Slide Down Contact Me Form/lulzy.php

This implies that

- you have opened your HTML from your local hard drive (instead of serving it from a local web server)
- and you therefore don't have any PHP processor in there (though *lulzy.php* seems really to be non-existent in the specified folder)

Furthermore, you forgot to add `name` attributes to your form fields (as others have already mentioned here) and you declared the *method* attribute as the form's action by accident:

```
<form action="lulzy.php" action="post">

<!-- This should be right: -->
<form action="lulzy.php" method="post">
```

---

**Use a captcha?** <sub>(see [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759767/my-php-code-is-not-working/16759884?noredirect=1#comment24148589_16759884))</sub>

I would definitely add one if you keep your form sending direct emails. There are several libraries out there - depending on your traffic (private or commercial site?) - you might use [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). You could also roll your own, but better use intelligent questions or something only a human could solve instead of an image.


Nevertheless, you should also take your users into consideration. **Possible spam beating vs. user experience**.

A completely other option besides verifying human beings would be to not send the emails to your (personal) email address, save them to your database instead and create a simple notification system on your own. That way, you have more granular filter control.

Comment: Ok. I will try to change everything as suggested but how can I test if my PHP code is working before I upload everything to a web server? Everything is still on my local hard drive. Is there any way???

Comment: @C.Felipe Just install a local web server. I would recommend [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which comes packaged with Apache (web server), PHP, Perl, phpMyAdmin and some other tools.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to do that. Hope it's easy to use so I can test my codes!

Comment: @C.Felipe You're welcome. The installation (at least under Windows) is very easy. One should actually always develop and test one's scripts locally and only deploy to the 'real' web server when going in production mode.

Comment: @ComFreak Thanks again. I appreciate your advices so far. Btw, do you think this is good enough or I should better insert CAPTCHA script? Is it hard to add CAPTCHA?

Comment: @C.Felipe I've added a paragraph to my answer ;)

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks a lot. If I manage to implement all these suggestions this will look great! Appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 6):

You need to have name attribute on each of your form input's

```
<input type="text" name ="fullName" placeholder="Please enter your full name here" required />
```

Same for `email` and `textarea` , and `method='post'` instead of `action='post'`

Your php needs to be on your server not on your desktop.

Comment: Why would that give the "Firefox can't find the file at ..." error?

Comment: This is useful, but not THE answer.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add name attributes:

```
<form action="lulzy.php" method="post">
        <h6><img src="img/person.png" alt="" /> Name</h6>

    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your full name here" required />
        <h6><img src="img/email.png" alt="" /> E-mail</h6>

    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Please enter your e-mail address" required/>
        <h6><img src="img/message.png" alt="" /> Message</h6>

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message..." required/></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `method="POST"` instead of `action="post"`

your declaring action twice and not declaring your `method` at all of how the form is posting to your PHP script

You also for your name attributes like the other answers state